# What was the white column?

Tags: known-space, man-kzin-wars

In *Man-Kzin Wars 14* there is a short story entitled "The White Column" by Hal Colebatch.  The story describes the last clairvoyant vision of a "far-seer" who was asked to find "the most advanced artifact existing a hundred years from now." The vision produced by the seer was of a white column of unknown scale with tiny figures moving around the base of it.  The whole scene in the vision played out somewhere in the Northern hemisphere on Earth, apparently.  The story ends with the following enigmatic sentence:

> But there had just been time to see the white column, on a soundless beam of light, lift from the ground, turn towards the Pleiades, and vanish.

I've reread the story a few times and have not been able to make any sense of the vision or the ending.  The story talks about environmental decay and nuclear proliferation as being future bugaboos forecast earlier by this seer.  That along with a reference to Basil Shackleton as another burnt-out seer seems to set the time of the events in the story around 1950-1960.  I think that the ending of the story was an allusion to some significant event in the history of Known Space between 1950 and 2050 (otherwise what's the point), but I can't think of anything that fits, except something pedestrian like a traditional rocket launch.

**What was the white column and what was it doing?**

Comment: A great column of light makes me think of the laser drive on *Angel's Pencil*, but that wouldn't fit into the timeline.

Comment: It might be an earlier significant human ship -- one of the first interstellar colony ships (they'd been sending them for a while before the *Angel's Pencil*, or even an early interplanetary ship (e.g. one of the Belt colony ships).

Comment: I tried to provide an answer for you, but it's far from complete. Save your bounty for a full answer (if there is one)

Comment: @WolfieSmith Don't discount your efforts; what you've managed to piece together is well worth the bounty, especially given that I got no answers at all for the last seven years.  I tried asking Colebatch with no result, but the contact information I dug up could have been incorrect.  I think he's passed on since then, so too late now.

Comment: Have you tried the guys at larryniven.net? Or the man himself? It's not technically a Niven story, but he's got notes and dates that Colebatch must have used.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the white column in question is the first colony ship, launching off to found what becomes the Wunderland Colony.

*Disclaimer: before coming across this question, I had only read one Known Space story, so I've had to rely on research provided by others to come to this conclusion.*

*As such, this answer is only my **opinion** based on limited reading. **It is far from a definitive answer, and should not be taken as such**.*

*Timeline dates taken from [larryniven.net](http://www.larryniven.net/timeline.shtml) and [Known Space Timeline](https://sites.google.com/site/knownspacetimeline/)*

> There was a flat, reddish plain. In the center was a white column, with what appeared to be some sort of decoration at the top. The microphones recorded a whistling wind. There were what might have been low buildings or paving nearby, but scale and size were impossible to tell.

I believe this is a ramjet rocket sitting on it's launchpad. The long column shape is consistent with rockets we know in the real world, and the general design of ramjet rockets as depicted in the various books, most notably the [*Angel's Pencil*](https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/Angel%27s_Pencil_(ship)), so named because of it was an extreme example of this design. I believe the 'sort of decoration at the top' eludes to the equipment for the [ramscoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet), probably stored for launch. The 'whistling wind' could be the sound of a fusion drive 'idling', distorted by distance.

> I noticed tiny things, possibly insects, were moving at the base of the column. As I watched, they moved into or under the low structure near it.

This is the groundcrew moving away into safe structures prelaunch.

> But there had just been time to see the white column, on a soundless beam of light, lift from the ground, turn towards the Pleiades, and vanish in a flash.

Takeoff, presumably via fusion drive until they get up to speed to engage the ramscoop.

So, now we've established(!) it is a rocket launch the seer is seeing, we need to establish *which* rocket launch. To do this, we need to establish when this tale takes place.

The mention of [Basil Shackleton](https://www.prints-online.com/basil-shackleton-photographer-esp-subject-14123079.html) is the first clue. Basil was the subject of the now-discredited [Soal-Goldney Experiments](https://www.nature.com/articles/245052a0) into precognition in the early 1940s, and died in 1943, so we can assume we're some time after those experiments at least. The newspaper headlines taken from a few weeks in the future (*Nuclear proliferation. Environmental decay. The blow-up getting nearer.*), coupled with the retinal scanner and the opti-encephalograph gives a 60s sci-fi vibe, but that may just be me. I can't see this being set after the moon landings, as I feel the idea of manned rockets flight would be so ubiquitous by then that at least *one* person should have made the connection. My guesstimation would be that the scene is set in the 60s, but I accept this is a bit vague, so I'm willing to accept it could off by a decade or so, not that it matters.

We known the visions are a hundred years in the future:

> “The most advanced artifact existing a hundred years from now.”

So we're looking for a plot-significant rocket launch sometime around the 2060s, give or take a decade.

Assuming we take the [Ringworld Role-Playing Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringworld_(role-playing_game)) as canon - *which we should, as the creator of the game worked with Larry Niven to put together a set of rules for all the other *Known Space* writers to follow to help keep continuity between books ([see chapter 25 of *Scatterbrain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatterbrain_(book))). If that doesn't make the game canon in a shared universe, I don't know what does* - then we have a date for the setting of Wunderland Colony of 2091, and a launch date given as 2061, which certainly fits, but is still far from concrete evidence in itself. For this, we need to look at other, less literal clues within the story that the author has left for us, namely the two stories *within* the story.

First let's deal with the story of the crossbow. The simple meaning is plain: the scientists in the tale-within-a-tale were expecting to find an advanced weapon, and failed to recognise the simpler crossbow due to this expectation. The crossbow was, of course, a sign that mankind had regressed in the future due to our baser nature.

In our tale it's the opposite: the military people may have *asked* to see the most advanced thing, but the story of the crossbow symbolises their internal pessimism, so when they see the rocket, it is so far outside of what they expected to see (and so large in scale) that they cannot comprehend what it is and assume that it is a single ruin; a sign of our natural tendency to destruction, instead of the glorious symbol of human spirit that it actually is.

The crossbow symbolism also works on a few other levels, which may or may not be deliberate:

'Crossbow' was the codename given to the [WWII operation to identify and target the German VI & VII rocket launch sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Crossbow).

The rocket technology of the colony ships would end up being used to defeat the much more technologically advanced invading Kzinti fleet, making it the space-fighting equivalent of a crossbow, figuratively and quite literally.

The second clue is the story within the poem [*Ozymandias*](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46565/ozymandias). The simple meaning is plain: for all his bluster, ego and vanity, man is doomed to dust, and his works will be lost to the sands of time.

> "My name is Ozymandias, King of Kings / Look on my Works, ye Mighty, and despair! / Nothing beside remains. Round the decay / Of that colossal Wreck, boundless and bare / The lone and level sands stretch far away.”

However, again, the truth points to quite the opposite: the inscription *Shelley* based his poem on *actually* read (and this is [according to Diodorus of Sicily](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/articles/69503/percy-bysshe-shelley-ozymandias), who was there at the time and should be trusted more than a poet 1800 years later):

> "King of Kings Ozymandias am I. If any want to know how great I am and where I lie, let him outdo me in my work.”

Which is a much more positive message about human endeavour than Shelley's version. In fact, it's written more as a challenge to the reader to strive further, to accomplish more, to be even better than he was - "You think you're better than me? Prove it!". While I can't *guarantee* that Colebatch was aware of this when he wrote the story, and he is sadly no longer around to confirm nor deny, I choose to believe he did, as it fits the theme so perfectly.

The Ozymandias reference also works on another level, which may or may not be deliberate:

Ozymandias was a real king, more commonly known as [Ramesses II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramesses_II), The Great Ancestor. He is also believed to be the Pharoah of the Exodus. **Great Ancestor? Exodus? First colony ship?**

I believe the dates implied and these hints by the author confirm my hypothesis:

The White Column is the first colony ship, launching off to found what will become the Wunderland Colony. The site of the first human settlement outside of the Sol system. The site of the first Kzin attack on a human settlement 300 years later.

The beginning of mankind's expansion into space, and the beginning of the whole Man/Kzin Wars come down to that one launch.

Does that count as a significant event? ;)